# ggplot2 labels hidden behind bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

So I have this code:

```
ggplot(aes(x=Year,y=Household.Expenditure.Total,
             fill=Household.Expenditure.on.Tobacco,
             label=Expenditure.on.Tobacco.as.a.Percentage.of.Expenditure))+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_text_repel()+
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1985,2015,by=5))+
  labs(x="Year",
       y="Household expenditure on tobacco and Household expenditure total",
       title="The comparison of Household expenditure on tobacco \nand 
Household expenditure total over years ",
       caption="data form kaggle")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,vjust = 1))
```

Bare in mind that I have ggrepel installed and running. But my plot looks like this:

[image: All the labels are hidden behind the graph]

I've looked at other questions but didn't find anything similar to this. If you think there's one that can help me or if you need more info let me know. Thanks!

Comment: moving the geom_text_repel to after the geom_col will ensure labels are drawn on top, but geom_text_repel is probably not the best tool here. geom_text should do fine.

Comment: Hey! Now there are no lines but the numbers are somewhere between the top of the bars and the background! I'm so sorry i'm new here, and i still haven't figure out how to add a picture. Any idea on how to put the numbers within the bars?

Comment: Just use `geom_text` and play around with the `vjust` and `nudge_y` parameters. It will be much easier.

Comment: Yes, `vjust` did the job. Thank you @Axeman!

Comment: It would be great ggrepel also worked with barplots.
You can manually adjust your example because is very simple because the bars height grow smoothly. But when you have a mess of small and large bars and the text doesn't fit well between several of them things get complicated.